# Use Sockets in multiple *.cpp files

Tags: c++, sockets, server

As you can see in the Title box, I´d like to find a way how to use my sockets in multiple cpp files.

```cpp
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")


void main()
{
  WSADATA wsaData;
  WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsaData);

  SOCKET slisten,client;

  slisten = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  //and so on...

}
```

This is the way I use the `ws2_32.lib` but just in main.
I´d like to use the socket `client`in other files, so I`m able to
send data wherever I want. The socket is declared as a global variable.
I´d be nice if someone can give me an advice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question seems not specific to sockets, but to global variables in general.
If you need to create a global variable (a socket, in this case) which must be accessible by multiple compilation units:

- You define the global variable in one single compilation unit (i.e. one cpp file)
- You declare the variable with the `extern` statement in all the other compilation units that need to use it.

Some further information:

- If your program is multithreaded, you will need to protect the global variable from concurrent usage through a `std::mutex`
- The order of inizialization of global variables across different compilation units has *undefined* behavior. This is known as [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). You can impose a specific order by using, e.g. the SIngleton or a some kind of Factory design patterns.

Comment: Put in main.cpp `SOCKET slisten,client;` and in Communication.* `extern SOCKET slisten,client`. 

However, I strongly suggest you to read a good C or C++ book before going ahead. It seems you are missing the whole background about declaration/definition and compilation units. You may end up in trouble...

You may read "The C Programming Language" (by Kernighan & Ritchie) or "The C++ programming language" 4th edition (by Stroustrup).

Answer (score 1):

use "[extern](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-extern-keyword-in-c/)" keyword - which tells the linker that this is defined already somewhere else of this scope and should be linkedin..

main file -

```
SOCKET slisten,client;
```

other file:

```
extern SOCKET slisten,client;
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDfDnsvEodQ

Comment: Ew, videos are the worst format of explaining anything related to programming. Otherwise fine answer.

Comment: @Zharf weill there is also a link, and if not google is your friend too :) and if you like the answer why not upvote it :)